# Setup picamera on Buildroot 2017.2

Tags: raspberry-pi3, buildroot

I'm looking to install the picamera component on Raspberry Pi 3, using Buildroot 2017.2 as OS.

The output of `python -c "import picamera"` is the follow:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/picamera/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    from picamera.exc import (
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/picamera/exc.py", line 41, in <module>
    import picamera.mmal as mmal
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/picamera/mmal.py", line 47, in <module>
    from .bcm_host import VCOS_UNSIGNED
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/picamera/bcm_host.py", line 47, in <module>
    _lib = ct.CDLL('libbcm_host.so')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 362, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: File not found
```

The information system shown `uname -a` are:

```
Linux buildroot 4.4.43-v7 #7 SMP Tue Aug 1 17:56:58 CEST 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

I've already set `gpu_mem=128`.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Did you enable the rpi-firmware package? That package should install libbcm_host.so.

Comment: Yes, the file that you meant was if rpi-userland package, so I enabled it and now I get another error.

`/usr/bin/python2.7: symbol 'mmal_port_pool_create': can't resolve symbol
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
    from picamera.exc import (
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/picamera/exc.py", line 41, in <module>
    import picamera.mmal as mmal
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/picamera/mmal.py", line 49, in <module>
    _lib = ct.CDLL('libmmal.so')
...`

The libmmal.so exists in /usr/lib folder. @Arnout

Comment: You left out the interesting bit: *which* symbol it can't resolve. That indicates there is another library (with that symbol) that must be loaded.